# How to do Filled and Outlined at the same time TextInputLayout android?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-custom-view, material-components-android

I used `<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` but I will also accept other options or libs

Expected result:

focused:
[image: focused]
unfocused:
[image: unfocused]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using a custom TextInputLayout Style which inherits from `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox` and a custom background selector for TextInputEditText.

Create the TextInputLayout in xml like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/emailTextInputLayout"
    style="@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
       android:id="@+id/emailTextInputEditText"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
       android:hint="Email"
       android:importantForAutofill="no"
       android:singleLine="true" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

where `@style/MyTextInputLayoutStyle` is a custom style which inherits from `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox` like below:

```
<style name="MyTextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
   <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
   <item name="boxStrokeWidth">0dp</item>
   <item name="boxStrokeWidthFocused">0dp</item>
   <item name="hintTextColor">#7d8b9f</item>
</style>
```

and `@drawable/edit_text_background` is a Drawable Selector to change the background based on the default and focused states like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f0f5fa"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#b5c3f6"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f0f5fa"/>
            <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#b5c3f6"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**Results will be like below:**

[image: focused]
[image: unfocused]

Answer (score -1):

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    <!--have your custom style/text appearance for hint and text input-->
    //android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
    //app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintTextAppearance"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:id="@+id/edEmail"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="Email"
      android:importantForAutofill="no"
      android:singleLine="true" />
  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: 1. its not expected: no have outline